# Gatling - exit Iteration on error and start new iteration and logging

Tags: scala, gatling

In gatling,I want to exit the interation on failure and start a new iteration. I have used exitHereIfFailed but see that it completely stops the scenario. althought my scenario is configured to run for 30 minutes. Please advice if I have got this right.

Also how do I  handle the errors in Gatling, and print to a file with relavent details. In my example below on check failure, I want to exit the iteration and write the details to a file will details like username, timestamp etc.. Kindly help.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef.{exec, _}
import io.gatling.http.Predef.{http, _}
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import scala.language.postfixOps 

object Login {
            val login = group("ABC_Login") {
            feed(userFeeder)
                    .exec(http("Login")
                    .post(uri16 + "/login")
                    .formParam("username", "${username}")
                    .formParam("password", "${password}")
                    .formParam("login", "Login")
                    .check(substring("Welcome to ABC Professionalllll")))
                .exitHereIfFailed 
}
//scenario definition and injection setup

val BP01AddSearch = scenario("BP01Search").during(30 minutes)
            {
                pace(50 seconds)
                .exec(Homepage.homepage, Login.login, SearchLink.search,  Logout.logout)

            }

setUp(BP01AddSearch.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol)  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tryMax`, see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/scenario/#trymax

```scala
during(30 minutes) {
  tryMax(5) {
    pace(50 seconds)
      .exec(Homepage.homepage, Login.login, SearchLink.search,  Logout.logout)
  }
}
```